# How to Set Session or Cookie Life Time in Laravel Lumen

Tags: php, session, laravel, cookies, lumen

How do I set Cookie/Session life-time in Lumen. In laravel this can be found in the `app/config/session.php` but since Lumen uses `.env` file for its configuration, how do I set the life time of sessions? Also when I put a value in a session, `Session::put($key,$value)` it doesn't last for more than 3 requests, the value becomes lost, could this be due to it's life-time or something else?

just in case, this is what my `.env` file looks like:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=SomeRandomKey!!!

APP_LOCALE=en
APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=en

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set it with `SESSION_LIFETIME=60`

More options for session config can be found from here https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.0/config/session.php

Comment: but why is that the value put into the session are lost after every three or two request. i'm using cookie as my session driver, i really don't wanna raise another question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

it is simple

just go to `app/config/session.php` and set `'lifetime' => 0`

Comment: This is how it is set in Laravel major framework not Lumen which is Laravel Micro-Framework. http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/